# how to add a range of numbers into a list using for loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to iterate through a range of numbers (e.g. 2-6), get the range of each number into a list and after that save each number as a key and its range as a value in a dictionary. My output should be:
`dicti={2:[1], 3:[1,2],4:[1,2,3],5:[1,2,3,4]}`
or
 `dicti={[2]:[1], [3]:[1,2],[4]:[1,2,3],[5]:[1,2,3,4]}`.

How can I do that? I started as below but apparently what I'm trying to do does not work.

```
for i in list(range (2,6)):
    for j in list(range(1,i)):
        zipped=zip(i,j)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: @OmG List comp. is great and Pythonic.  Mine is using defaultdict to get the same result. check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily by iterating over the specified range:

```
result = dict((x, list(range(1, x))) for x in range(2,6))
```

run it [online](https://trinket.io/python/8ac261886b).

Comment: @DanielHao Right. Changed `range(x)` to `range(1,x)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way - using the `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(2, 6):
    for j in range(1, i):
        dd[i].append(j)
```